# Is TCP socket connection good for continuous socket opening/closing

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

I'm working on a project where I need to send data (not much, ~300B(+-100) at once) every 5 minutes. On one side is a raspberry pi with apache2 server and an additional PHP script which serves as a TCP socket server.

On the other side, there are multiple clients, which connect to TCP socket server. Connection is established by the server, they exchange the data and then the socket is closed. This happens every 5 minutes per client (so if I have 100 clients, the socket Will be opened and closed 20 times a minute).

Is this a good way to handle such connections, or should I do it somehow differently? Are PHP scripts fine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either this or connecting each client once and keeping the connection alive. With the numbers you're specifying both are valid choices, but a socket is a resource and the OS can't really allocate new resources ad infinitum. Therefore, it will have to reuse them, so this approach of opening and closing is one that scales well since currently unused sockets can be recycled.

Now on the other hand, if your server is running apache2 for the sole reason of running a PHP script which only serves as a TCP socket server then I'd say this is not the best way to make this. You can probably use [WebSockets](http://socketo.me/) (still using PHP) and run php via the CLI and not need to have apache2 running.

Comment: No, I need apache2 running, since there is a website hosted on this raspberry too. I really like PHP since I need to send data from database and it is easy to connect to DB with PHP PDO. I'll try my way and see what happens if there are multiple clients connecting. Btw, I'm running the php script via terminal (rc.local file which runs the script on boot)

Comment: Ah, then what you're doing is fine then.

Comment: Alirght, I Will do it this way then, thank you for your answers. Any suggestions about security?

Comment: @Rok Security is a much bigger topic as it depends on what you need to achieve with it. If you're worried about the packets getting intercepted then HTTPS should be enough, but if you need to verify the client has the credentials to send data then you'll need some sort of basic HTTP authentication in place (both can be configured on apache).

Comment: The data that is received by PHP program is actually sent via python TCP socket client, data is a clients ID (the ID is then used to get the data for the appropriate client). Since the website is "private" - it doesn't even have domain I think I don't need much of security.

Answer (score 0):

So if I read this right, you have remote clients that are opening a TCP Connection to a PHP app hosted on an Apache HTTP Server running on the raspberry Pi 2.
A client will connect to the server every 5 minutes and send about 300 bytes (+/- 100 bytes) of data.
So, that's a TCP connection opened every 5 second. This is nothing for the Raspberry Pi unless it take a huge number of CPU to process the 300 bytes you get.

I would not recommend to try to keep the network connection alive for 5 minutes (either using TCP keep-alive and/or HTTP keep-live and/or using web sockets) since the load is so low, you will put more stress on the system trying to keep 100 connections alive than to let them re-connect every 5 minutes.

Comment: Yep pretty much, the PHP script (the TCP socket server) is run via rc.local file on boot. Those 300 bytes come from the database (the table is not big, I expect ~300 entries with 100 clients).